# React native include static TXT or JSON file

Tags: react-native, file, expo

I was woundering how I could pull this off. If I save a TXT or JSON file in a directory in my RN project, what would be the easiest way to do this, so I can read the files content with expo file system?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a .json file in src directory i think the easiest way to read it is using require

```
const data = require('./src/data.json');
export default ()=>{
   return <View>
      <Text>{data.value}</Text>
   </View>
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an error saying the module doesn't exist